# Setting selected index not working, jquery .Val()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, jquery-selectors

I have tried all of these various ways to set the value of the select.  I only know the id/index value and not the text description.  None of these work in IE and all except the last work in FireFox.

I have set alerts to make sure the contactList.PerType_ID has a value and that is a number

Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
var perId = parseInt(contactList.PerType_ID);

$('#ddContactType').val(perId);

$('#ddContactType').val(3);

$('#ddContactType option[value=3]').attr('selected', 'selected');

$('#ddContactType option[value='+perId+']').attr('selected', 'selected'); //does not work in ff
```

**Turns out the control I was trying to set did not exist yet in IE.  I moved a call to the method before a service call and the control loads fine using all of the methods I listed above and the only response I got below.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$('#ddContactType option[value=' + perId + ']').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass parameter as string:

```
$('#ddContactType').val("3");
```